# How to draw dash line in MapPolyline?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

How I can draw dash line in MapPolyline? Setting the property in LineItem to style: Qt.DashStyle  has no effect.

```
MapPolyline {
        id: nearestMapPolyline
        z: m_mapPolygon.z
        visible: nearestMapPolyline.visible
        smooth: true
        antialiasing: true
        line.color: m_mapPolyline.lineColor
        line.width: m_mapPolyline.lineWidth
        onPathChanged: {
            nearestDataModel.clear();

            for (var i = 0; i < nearestMapPolyline.path.length - 1; ++i) {
                nearestDataModel.append({ "p1": i, "p2": i + 1});
            }
        }
        ListModel {
            id: nearestDataModel
        }
        Instantiator {
            model: nearestDataModel
            delegate: MapItemGroup {
                Anchor {
                    id: nearestPoint1
                    coordinate: nearestMapPolyline.path[p1]
                }
                Anchor {
                    id: nearestPoint2
                    coordinate:  nearestMapPolyline.path[p2]
                }
                LineItem {
                    opacity: 1
                    color: m_mapPolyline.lineColor
                    lineWidth: m_mapPolyline.lineWidth
                    style: Qt.DashLine
                    frontier: m_mapPolyline.frontier
                    visible: m_mapPolygon.visible
                    x1: nearestPoint1.x
                    y1: nearestPoint1.y
                    x2: nearestPoint2.x
                    y2: nearestPoint2.y
                    z: nearestMapPolyline.z

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        cursorShape: active ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
                    }
                }
            }
            onObjectAdded: map.addMapItemGroup(object)
            onObjectRemoved: map.removeMapItemGroup(object)
        }

        function clearPath() {
            nearestMapPolyline.path = []
        }
    }
```

P.s. I use MapPolyline because our project use MapPolygon in bundle MapPolyline.
Maybe smbd know about this problem? And how to fix it.

P.p.s. In c++ style for LineItem looks like

```
void LineItem::setDashPattern(const QVector<qreal> &pattern) noexcept 
{
#ifndef USE_QPAINTER
if (_dashPattern == pattern)
    return;
_dashPattern = pattern;
setStyle(Qt::CustomDashLine);
#else
if (_pen.dashPattern() == pattern)
    return;
_pen.setDashPattern(pattern);
emit styleChanged(_pen.style());
#endif
emit dashPatternChanged(pattern);
update();
}
```

Comment: what `LineItem` is? If that is your custom item please provide [mcve]